# Getting error status:unknown job while starting MongoDB using Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am not able to start MongoDB in my Ubuntu machine. First I follow below steps to install MongoDB in my Ubuntu system.

```
1->sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

2-> echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

3-> sudo apt-get update

4-> sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

5-> service mongod start
```

While I tried to start the MongoDB I got the following message rather than its starting.

```
status:unknown job : mongod
```

I am trying to also remove the `mongodb.lock` file from `/var/lib/mongodb` folder but unable to remove here I need to start the MongoDB service.

Comment: Which version are you using for mongodb..?

Comment: @MitalGajjar : version` v3.0.14`.

Comment: try this command to start mongodb : sudo mongod

Comment: @MitalGajjar : Same issue found after running your command.

Comment: I m getting same issue  when first time i install mongodb. so i try to reinstall mongodb then it works fine. so check it after reinstalling hope it helps you...

Comment: i deleted also mongod.lock file and there are some information i found `etc/init/mongodb.conf removing the line "limit nofile 20000"` but in this version i found `limit nofile 64000 64000` line that same file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130275/discussion-between-satya-and-mital-gajjar).

Answer (score 0):

ok try this one:

```
 sudo apt-get purge mongodb-stable
sudo apt-get install mongodb-stable
```

(remove the lock file if present in /var/lib/mongodb)

Then edit /etc/init/mongodb.conf removing the line "limit nofile 20000"

Comment: I did as per above but still same issue.